# Hive SQL: obtaining a list of max values corresponding to each year in a certain range

Tags: sql, hive, range

I have a dataset like this:

```
ticker | value | year
  A       1      2008
  A       2      2008
  A       5      2010
  A       6      2006
  B       7      2010
```

I'm trying to write a Hive SQL that returns a GROUP BY on ticker where the value is a list of max values corresponding to every year in a certain range. 
In this case, if the range is 2008-2010 it would return something like (not really sure how the structure of the result can actually look like, I hope you can understand what I mean anyway):

```
A [(year: 2008, value: 2), (year: 2009, value: 0 (found no value for this year)), (year: 2010, value: 5)]
B [(year: 2008, value: 0), (year: 2009, value: 0), (year: 2010, value: 7)]
```

In particular I don't understand how to ask Hive to return a list of values corresponding to the range of a certain value in the dataset. I'd be glad if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need  just valid values  You could use a where between

```
    select  ticker, max(value), year
    from my_table 
    where year between 2008 and 2010 
    group by ticker, year

    or if need  all the year you could build the set using union  

   select  m.ticker, max(coalesce(m.value,0)), m.year
    from  (
        select 2008 year
        union
        select 2009 year
        union 
        select 2010 year
        ) t
    left join my_table m on t.year = m.year
    group by ticker, year
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a row for every ticker and year, then use `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` to bring in the values.  For years, it is easy enough to generate the values using a subquery:

```
select t.ticker, y.year, coalesce(max(d.value, 0)) as max_value
from (select distinct ticker from dataset) t cross join
     (select 2008 as year union all select 2009 union all select 2020) y left join
     dataset d
     on d.ticker = t.ticker and d.year = y.year
group by t.ticker, y.year
order by t.ticker, y.year;
```

For larger ranges you could use a subquery like this:

```
(select row_number() over () + 2008 - 1 as year
 from dataset
 limit 3
) y
```